# Texturing edges of a procedurally generated polygon

Tags: unity, textures, graphics, uv-mapping

I'm generating a polygon from code to display unit ranges in my game. Here's how it looks so far:

[image: Polygon]

I would love to be able to now use my texture and only apply it to the edges of this polygon (imagine a stroke with no fill). Could someone point me in the right direction with this issue?

Comment: Presumably you've considered using a LineRenderer, or using your polygon mesh creation logic to create your own polygon strip around the outside, or using an outlining shader. Have you run into any specific problems with pursuing one or another of these directions?

Comment: Actually, the idea of using an outlining shader has for some reason completely escaped me. Guess I've been deep down into that triangulation code for too long. Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question if you get partway into a solution and need help completing/polishing it.